# How to develop a https nodejs web app so that security warning doesn't show

Tags: node.js

I have changed the protocol on my website to `http` instead of `https`.

The following is my code that serves the server.

```
const https = require('https');

const httpsOptions = {
    key : fs.readFileSync('example.key'),
    cert : fs.readFileSync('example.crt')
};

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log('server listening at 3000')
});
```

But now whenever I try to enter my locally run site `https://localhost:3000`, it shows security warning that the website is not safe anymore.

So I went to google docs https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/avoid-not-secure-warn to see how to remove the sign and it says 'create the entire website as https' but what I don't understand is all my sites are already `https`. To see all my views `https` must be used instead of `http`.

Is the above code not enough to make all the pages `https`? if it is, what else do I have to do so that I don't frighten my clients by showing warnings when they enter my site?

Comment: You don't have certificates that google thinks are safe. It might be that your website is safe, but google cannot check the validity.

Comment: @Randy how do I resolve that? do I use different hash algorithm?

Comment: You are missing a trusted certificate, you need to buy one or self sign one 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru I have the certificate

Comment: Which CA did you get the certificate from? Or is it self-signed?

Comment: `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -nodes -keyout example.key -out example.crt -days 3650` This is what I used @JoeClay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your certificates are probably not signed, especially if you created them yourself, you need to send them to get signed by certified SSL certificated distributers. You can check [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/top-reliable-ssl-certificates) blog post for more info on certificate issuers.

[Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) is a free certificate issuer and you can automate the process of renewing them, so you don't have to worry on that part.

Comment: oh... so I can't just create one myself?

Comment: You can create one, that's not the problem, but self created certificates are not signed, so google doesn't trust them, because you are not on google's whitelist. I'd advice you use let's encrypt since it'll automatically solve your problems

Comment: oh... okay. Thanks I didn't know that